# Unable to read body of mail

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am not able to read the body text of mails. 
Mail is not encrypted.

I have `$Abstract` property for mails in lotus notes Document property  as follows:

```
Field Name: $Abstract
Data Type: Text List
Data Length: 62 bytes
Seq Num: 1
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: SEAL SUMMARY 

"p{margin-bottom:1em}p{margin-bottom:1em}&nbsp; Hello Tony,"
```

`$Abstract` value prefixed with some invalid charecters.
Is my problem with invalid abstract property?

Iam using the following code in C# to read the Body of mail

_DocInbox = _serverDatabase.GetDocumentByID(strArrayOfIds[iIndex].ToString());
  BodyText = ((object[])_DocInbox.GetItemValue("Body"))[0] as String;

GetItemValue function should return the body of mail. But it is returning null string.

Is there any other function to read mail body in c#.
  Please help me.

Comment: Do you try to read the mail programmatically? Then post the code you use... You have to look at the item "Body" to get the data... If you just can't read the mail, then this belongs to superuser not stackoverflow...

Comment: Yes I am reading the mail programmaticallyby the following code. BodyText = readMailAttribute(CurDocInbox, "Body");

Comment: readMailAttribute is not a standard- function. I have no idea what happens inside that function. And you don't even state the language. Please: Post the code that you have. Post, what it is supposed to do and then post what it does instead... Then someony might help.

Comment: Iam using the following code in C# to read the Body of mail
 
  NotesDocument MailDoc =  m_NotesDatabase.CreateDocument();
 
  BodyText = readMailAttribute(MailDoc, "Body");

  readMailAttribute function should return the body of mail. But it is not returning null string.

  Is there any other function to read mail body in c#.

Comment: Again: Edit your question and put that code into the question...

Comment: Where is the source for readMailAttribute()? That's not a standard Notes API call, so it must be somebody's custom code. Also, please show the actual code where the $Abstract item is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Use NotesDocument's `GetFirstItem()` to get the NotesRichTextItem and `GetUnformattedText()` to get RichTextItem's content as plain text.

```
...
BodyText = _DocInbox.GetFirstItem("Body").GetUnformattedText();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

When iam using  Body = CurDocInbox.GetItemValueString("Body") am getting an error that


'Domino.NotesDocument' does not contain a definition for 'GetItemValueString' and no extension method 'GetItemValueString' accepting a first argument of type 'Domino.NotesDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Then i have used the below code to get body: 

           Object[] ni = (Object[])CurDocInbox.Items;
                 for (int x = 0; x < ni.Length; x++)
                {
                    NotesItem item = (NotesItem)ni[x];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
                    {
                        if (item.Name.ToLower() == "body" )
                        {

                              Body = item.Text;
                              Body = item.Values.ToString();

                            }
                      }
                 }

Comment: But body is still null.
values and text properties of item field is null.But ValueLength property of item is 10.

Comment: I didn't know that C# uses the LotusScript classes and not the Java classes. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.                                                                           I used the folllowing cobe:    NotesRichTextItem rtItem = (NotesRichTextItem)CurDocInbox.GetFirstItem("Body");
                String Body_new = rtItem.GetFormattedText(false, 0);                                 still it is getting null.

Comment: Does your document have really a field "Body"? Check this please in Notes client and in code with `if (rtItem != null) {...`

Comment: Yes document have field "Body".   rtItem != null                                      And i am able to see the body field in document property of mail in Lotus notes.